# How do I plot points in [x,y] format using Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Sorry, I'm a beginner and have no clue about plotting. I have four points: `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. How do I plot them using matplotlib?

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [2, 4]
c = [2.5, 4]
d = [4.5, 5]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Easy, use [`plt.scatter()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwie0ZDhh43qAhXDmeAKHT0GA4kQFjADegQIChAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmatplotlib.org%2Fapi%2F_as_gen%2Fmatplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html&usg=AOvVaw1QP7xlgrZc3PwRt0WT0o8R):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [1, 2]
b = [2, 4]
c = [2.5, 4]
d = [4.5, 5]

l = [a,b,c,d]

plt.scatter([i[0] for i in l], [i[1] for i in l])

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do I label the points a, b, c, d?

Comment: You can use [`plt.text`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) to label points, e.g. to label `a` you can do `plt.text(a[0], a[1], 'a')`.  You can also wrap this in a loop if you create a list of names

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is perfectly correct. Another possible way that I personally find a little cleaner would be to use Numpy to transpose the datapoints.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [1, 2]
b = [2, 4]
c = [2.5, 4]
d = [4.5, 5]

l = np.array([a,b,c,d]) #[[1,2], [2,4], [2.5,4], [4.5,5]]
datapoints = l.T        #[[1, 2, 2.5, 4.5], [2, 4, 4, 5]]

plt.scatter(datapoints[0], datapoints[1])

plt.show()
```

Even cleaner than this would be to do

```
x,y = l.T
plt.scatter(x, y)
```